# Diffeomorphism of $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ with a subspace of $\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb RP^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Consider the subspace $Y$ of $\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb RP^1$ defined by $$ Y=\{(x_1,x_2,[y_1:y_2])\in\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb RP^1 : x_1y_2=x_2y_1\} $$

This is clearly a well-defined subspace of $\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb RP^1$. Then consider the space $Z:=Y -(\{0\}\times \Bbb RP^1)$. I am asked to show that $Z$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$. I think I should first define a map from $Z$ to $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, but I can't think of an appropriate map. Is there any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your sure that your definition of $Y$ is correct? If it would say that $x_1y_2=x_2y_1$, then this would mean that $(x_1,x_2)$ is proportional to $(y_1,y_2)$. Then $Y$ would be the total space of the tautological bundle, which is diffeomorphic to a Moebius band. Then you have to remove the "central circle" of that Moebius band, and what you get is indeed diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @Andreas Cap Thanks I made an edit. How can we show that $Y$ is diffeomorphic to the moebius band? I havent learn about tautological bundle, yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't learned about the tautological bundle Andreas comment does not immediately translate to a map for you. There is a well defined map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}P^1$ defined by $f(y_1,y_2)=[y_1:y_2]$. This map is obviously surjective and can be shown to be smooth. Define $F:\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{0\} \to Z$ by
$$F(x_1,x_2)=\left(x_1,x_2,f(x_1,x_2)\right)$$
As Andreas mentioned, elements $(x_1,x_2,[y_1:y_2]) \in Z$ have the property that  $(x_1,x_2)$ is proportional to $(y_1,y_2)$. Use this observation to show that $F$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks. Then is the inverse of $F$ just simply $(x_1,x_2,[y_1:y_2])\mapsto (x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: Yes this is the inverse